# Problems with PHP version after upgrade to 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, php-5.2.x.x

I have 2 separate installations of Magento in different sub-domains on the same host.

The first one, my development store where I test upgrades, try out new add-ons etc. upgraded from 1.8.1 to 1.9.1 just fine (I used the upgrade in Magento Connect) apart from a couple of minor colour issues in a 3rd party template which were easily fixed.

I have just tried to upgrade the live store using exactly the same method and it crashed out part way through (got a cache flushing error in the Magento Connect console) and now I am getting an invalid PHP version error (says I need PHP 5.3.0 or newer). I have run phpinfo and I am getting 5.2.6 as the installed version.

This makes no sense at all, as the test store is running just fine with 5.2.6.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You have confirmed you are running the exact same version of PHP on your dev server?

Comment: The two installations are on the same server; it is shared hosting with a commercial host.

Answer (score 2):

The system requirements for version 1.9 are PHP5.4 or 5.5 You will have to update you current server to the newer version of PHP. In addition you will get a performance boost by going with PHP5.4 or higher

SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS FOR MAGENTO ENTERPRISE EDITION 1.14.1 AND COMMUNITY EDITION 1.9.1

Magento requires a LAMP or LNMP stack

**Operating System**
Linux x86-64

**Web Server**
Apache 2.x
Nginx 1.7.x

**Database**
MySQL 5.6 (Oracle or Percona)

**PHP**
PHP 5.4
PHP 5.5

**SSL**
A valid security certificate is required for HTTPS.
Self-signed SSL certificates are not supported.
SUPPORTED TECHNOLOGIES

**Redis**
REDIS can be used for session or cache storage

**Memcached**
Memcached can be used for session or cache storage
(EE Only)

**Apache Solr**
SOLR SEARCH can be used as a search provider

http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Comment: The two installations are on the same server, so I don't understand how the dev installation is working. I can't upgrade PHP as it is on commercial shared hosting.

Comment: I'm curious why there is a discrepancy between the requirements listed on magento.com and the requirements checked in `index.php`. If 5.4 is required for 1.9, why does `index.php` check for versions less than 5.3.0?

Answer (score 1):

the php version compare happens in the index.php, its very likely that it got changed, or not updated before.

Also, you run a very outdated version of php. There are a lot of security fixes, which were not backported to php 5.3 or even 5.2